# How apply granular per content rights in OAuth 2?

Tags: security, oauth-2.0, authorization

We know how to grant access through an access token and user info through identity token.

We know we can add roles claims to the identity token.

But in a permission access per content, I don't know how to use claims and tokens.

Think in the case that user A owners calendar with id 1, and him allows user B to read it.

The scope for user B to access throught a SPA to the REST services are:
Calendar.Read
Calendar.Write
Calendar.List

But in the case of calendar (id = 1) we want only a Calendar.Read scope.

How we can handle this case in OAuth?

Is any pattern?

Are there other protocol for this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OAuth 2.0 is certainly fit to handle that use case as well. You have two options:

1. assign a scope per calendar e.g. `Calendar.1.Read` (remember, scopes
   contents are not defined by OAuth 2.0 and can be dynamic)
2. use a type of opaque bearer access token that requires
   validation/introspection at the Authorization Server and pass a resource
   identifier on that call in addition to the access token, e.g. `Calendar.1`
   is the resource identifier and the scope associated with the access token
   is `Calendar.Read`

Comment: Calendar could be a claim with an array of claims? ej. `{'Claims':{'Calendar.Read':[1,5,8,12,19,45],'Calendar.Write':[1,3]}}` Or should be a new property in token like `'{Resources':[{'Calendar.1':'Calendar.Read'},'Calendar.2':'Calendar.Write']`

Comment: I would use scopes for the info, not claims. The format of scopes is free.